# Using standard library headers with CFFI

Tags: sockets, python-cffi

I am using Python and CFFI to write some unit tests for a library that I  have written in C, this library involves socket programming on Linux. The `.c` file is compiled into a shared library and then loaded using `ffi.dlopen()`.

Naturally the `struct sockaddr_in` structure is used which is defined in `netinet/in.h`, and in my case it is used within another structure.

```
typedef struct sDeviceSockAddr
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in deviceAddr;  
} tDeviceSockAddr;
```

I am using `ffi.cdef()` to define this structure. Running the unit test returns the (kind of expected) following error :

> TypeError: field 'tDeviceSockAddr.DeviceAddr' has ctype 'struct sockaddr_in' of unknown size

My first thought was how do I load the whole `netinet/in.h`, but being new to CFFI, I am not sure that this is the way to go.

Is it possible to load `netinet/in.h` correctly? if so, how? 
If not, what is the way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `ffi.dlopen()`, then you're out of luck.  The only way to do that would be to declare explicitly the struct sockaddr_in in your cdef, maybe by copy-pasting bits of the Linux headers, assuming you're on Linux---and then of course the result is not portable.

You may want instead of look into using a proper `ffibuilder` approach, which require a compiler at installation time but lets you use any external include file.  It's the mode described at https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#main-mode-of-usage.  In that mode you would write `struct sockaddr_in { ...; };` in the `cdef()`, with literally dot-dot-dot, if you don't need the content of struct sockaddr_in from Python; or if you do you can include the fields that you need, but be sure to also write "`...;`", which means "this is a partial declaration; please use the real header to fix the order of fields and total size of the structure".

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm on Linux, I've edited the post to include this information. I'm looking into your proposed solution.

Comment: Well after a long (and far from enjoyable) read of the CFFI documentation and many trials and errors, your solution worked . Again thank you !